# Can't use the iOS distribution in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, keychain, provisioning-profile

In my `Xcode 9` project I have the `Automatically manage signing` checked. I want to sign the application with the `iOS distribution` certificate. For some reasons, when I was creating the certificate I entered the name and email of another person. In the `keychain Access` I can see the public and private keys with the name of that person and under the private one, the `iPhone distribution` certificate. The problem is that in Xcode when I select the `Team`, I'm only getting the `iPhone developer` `signing certificate` and not the the `distribution` one. But from the `Build Setting` I can see the `iPhone distribution` in the select list of the `Code Signing Identity`. Once I select it, `Xcode` detect a conflict of the `provisioning profile` (because I change it manually and the `Automatically manage signing` is checked). I tried the solution of check then uncheck it and select the team but the problem is still here.

Comment: Please post the exact error message Xcode is giving you

Comment: @DipakKacha are you sure that the Automatically manage signing is only to manage iOS developer certificates?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. That can be used for both developer & Distribution. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1814/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Scheme under the Left top corner of App name Dropdown-->Edit Scheme is enabled to Release and not Debug for Archive and Testing also so automatically your Distribution is selected.

When you use the Automatic provisioning by default you are getting two profiles generated in Xocde One when you connect the device it used Dev Profile for debugging, but when you archive the build it autogenerates Distribution profile. If you have enterprise account, I would recommend having a universal distribution profile created and not Adhoc as it will always have to be updated with new Device ID added to be regenerated and recompiled the old app.

Answer (score 0):

you just uncheck "Automatically signing" option. Once you uncheck only profile selection option will be enabled. Select distribution profiles as shown in image.

[image]